# Evaluate integral using asymptotic methods

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function, laplace-method

I have to evaluate the following integral where $N$ is very large and $\lambda_\epsilon=\lambda+i\epsilon$. 
\begin{equation}
        I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}   \exp{\left \{ N\left (-m^2 -\frac{1}{2}\ln(\lambda_\epsilon - 2m) \right )\right\}}\mathrm{d}m 
\end{equation}

For these kind of integrals I usually have recourse to asymptotic methods, namely the Laplace method. However this methods seems to fail as I don't have a single maximum in my integration range. Moreover the complex number $\lambda_\epsilon$ bugs me a bit.

One told me to evaluate this integral using hypergeometric functions using an infinitesimal $\epsilon$. However I am completely unfamiliar with this.

Any advice or remarks are highly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Is $\epsilon$ a fixed quantity, or are you computing $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} I$ first and then considering the result for large values of $N$?

Comment: Here $\epsilon$ is fixed but indeed I will take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ at the very end. Any ideas?

Comment: To put some context, I am looking at the probability density of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of some matrix. To obtain the distribution I need to take the log of the integral, take the imaginary part, and then only, looking at the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $\ln$ denotes the principal value of the logarithm. $I$ can be evaluated in closed form in terms of two ${_1 \hspace {-1px} F_1}$ functions, but getting the asymptotics for those is not easy. Instead, we can apply the steepest descent method to the integral directly.

Assume $\epsilon > 0$ and $\lambda > 0$. The stationary points of $\phi(m) = -m^2 - \ln(\lambda + i \epsilon - 2 m)/2$ are at
$$m_{1, 2} =
 \frac {\lambda + i \epsilon \pm \sqrt {(\lambda + i \epsilon)^2 - 4}} 4.$$
The level curves of $\operatorname {Re} \phi$ look like this (the values increase from blue to magenta to red):

[image]

Because of the branch cut, we cannot deform the contour $(-\infty, \infty)$ to go through $m_1$ while avoiding the red regions. Therefore, we need to take a contour that goes through $m_2$ in the direction from left to right. This corresponds to $m = m_2 + \xi \sqrt {-2/\phi''(m_2)}$ near the saddle point $m_2$. Then
$$I \sim \sqrt {-\frac 2 {\phi''(m_2)}}
 \int_{\mathbb R} e^{N (\phi(m_2) - \xi^2)} d\xi =
\sqrt {-\frac {2 \pi} {N \phi''(m_2)}} \, e^{N \phi(m_2)},
\quad N \to \infty.$$

Comment: Excellent, this results enables me to recover the targeted spectral density. Thanks! One remark, when $\lambda<0$ do I have to find the stationary points again or do I simply use $m_1$?

Comment: The stationary points do not change, but if $\lambda < 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then $\operatorname{Im} m_1 < 0$, $\operatorname{Im} m_2 > 0$ and the branch cut is still in the upper half-plane. So yes, we just take $m_1$ instead of $m_2$. The configuration of the regions changes when $|\lambda|$ increases, but the only viable saddle point is always the one in the lower half-plane.